# How to use 'CImg' and it's basic functions

Tags: c++, image-processing, pixel, imaging, cimg

I have been trying to understand how to use CImg's drawing functions but the documentation isn't very clear to me. I just want to draw a pixel, but I don't understand how draw_point works. Can someone give some examples of draw_point and of how to declare an image? Also, is there a better alternative for C++? I just want the simplest imaging library there is for C++. I want to manipulate an empty image pixel by pixel. Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the CImg [tutorial](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html) to show how to use draw_point, the code is below:

```
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;

int main() 
{

    int size_x = 640;
    int size_y = 480;
    int size_z = 1;
    int numberOfColorChannels = 3; // R G B
    unsigned char initialValue = 0;

    CImg<unsigned char> image(size_x, size_y, size_z, numberOfColorChannels, initialValue);

    CImgDisplay display(image, "Click a point");

    while (!display.is_closed())
    {
        display.wait();
        if (display.button() && display.mouse_y() >= 0 && display.mouse_x() >= 0)
        {
            const int y = display.mouse_y();
            const int x = display.mouse_x();

            unsigned char randomColor[3];
            randomColor[0] = rand() % 256;
            randomColor[1] = rand() % 256;
            randomColor[2] = rand() % 256;

            image.draw_point(x, y, randomColor);
        }
        image.display(display);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The method *draw_point* have three overloads, that might confused use. I've used the following one:

```
template<typename tc>
CImg<T>& draw_point(const int x0, const int y0,
                    const tc *const color, const float opacity=1)
```

See [this](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#afbc21912a8c9419411d9fa82372056e3)  for details.

As for alternatives, if you want only to modify data pixel by pixel, perhaps you could work with the image as with raw data using libpng and libjpeg for input/output.

Anyway, I'd recommend you to read a bit more documentation about CImg. I've used it in some my projects and as for me it is very handy.